# Form data not saving when use DateField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

1. I am saving the form data into database but no success.
2. Actually when I include DateField in forms.py, its not saving any data
   but when excluded this field, it works fine.

Any possible reason for this problem.?

**Model:**

```
class CoWorker_Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker name.')
    email = models.EmailField('Email', help_text='Co-worker email.')
    address = models.TextField('Address', help_text='Co-worker address.')
    phone = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=20, help_text='Co-worker phone number.')
    companyName = models.CharField('Company Name', max_length=80, help_text='Co-worker company name.', null=True,
                                   blank=True)
    workingLocation = models.CharField('Working Location', max_length=50,
                                       help_text='Co-worker working '
                                                 'location.')
    workingShift = models.CharField('Working Shift', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker working shift.', default='')
    workingSpace = models.CharField('Working Space', max_length=50, help_text='Co-worker working space.', default='')
    teamMembers = models.CharField('Team Members', max_length=15, help_text="Co-Worker's Team Size.", default='')
    coworkerPicture = models.ImageField('Co-Worker Picture', upload_to='../media/images/co-woker-pictures'
                                        , help_text='Co-worker Picture.', default='', null=True, blank=True)
    joiningDate = models.DateField('Joining Date', help_text='Joining Date of Co-worker',
                                   auto_now_add=False,)
```

**Form**

```
class addCoWorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):


    teamMembers = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'placeholder': 'Team Members',
        'required': 'True'
    }))
    coworkerPicture = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
    }))
    joiningDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control formInput',
        'id': 'datePicker',
    }))
```

**View**

```
def Coworkers(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addCoWorkerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Co-Worker added successfully.')
            return redirect('admin/co-workers')
    else:
        form = addCoWorkerForm(request.GET)
```

please suggest best solution...?

Answer (score 0):

It is a model form but it does not know what model is mapped against this model.
To do that, add this in your form class

```
class Meta:
    model = Coworker
    fields = '__all__'
    # you can also use exclude to exclude fields you want.
```

This way your form will have fields for each of your model field by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Its added already in forms.py file.